# Azure Powershell Tagging VM's from CSV file

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, tagging

I'm quite new to Powershell scripting. I'm trying to generate tags for azure vm's from a CSV file.

Inside the CSV I have the following column headings:

- VMName
- Application
- SubCat
- Environment
- AppOwner
- Location

I've got a test CSV which literally has the following data in it:
MattTestVM, TestApp, TestSubapp, Dev, Matt, UK South

I'm not sure what i've put wrong in my code to get it to add the tags.

**Code**

```
#Set Credentials

$cred = Get-credential

# Sign-in with Azure account credentials

add-azurermaccount -credential $cred

# Select Azure Subscription

$subscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title "Select an Azure Subscription ..." -PassThru).SubscriptionId

#Select specified subscription ID

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId



$InputCSVFilePath = "C:\test\Tagging1.csv"

#Start loop

foreach ($eachRecord in $InputCSVFilePath)

{

    $VMName = $eachrecord.VMName

    $Application = $eachrecord.Application

    $SubCat = $eachrecord.SubCat

    $Environment = $eachrecord.Environment

    $AppOwner = $eachrecord.AppOwner

    $Location = $eachrecord.Location



     $r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $ResourceId -ErrorAction Continue



    if($r -ne $null)

    {

        if($r.tags)

        {

            # Tag - Application

            if($r.Tags.ContainsKey("Application"))

            {

                $r.Tags["Application"] = $Application

            }

            else

            {

                $r.Tags.Add("Application", $Application)

            }



            # Tag - SubCat

            if($r.Tags.ContainsKey("subCat"))

            {

                $r.Tags["subCat"] = $subCat

            }

            else

            {

                $r.Tags.Add("subCat", $subCat)

            }



            # Tag - Environment

            if($r.Tags.ContainsKey("Environment"))

            {

                $r.Tags["Environment"] = $Environment

            }

            else

            {

                $r.Tags.Add("Environment", $Environment)

            }



            # Tag - AppOwner

            if($r.Tags.ContainsKey("AppOwner"))

            {

                $r.Tags["AppOwner"] = $AppOwner

            }

            else

            {

                $r.Tags.Add("AppOwner", $AppOwner)

            }



            # Tag - Location

            if($r.Tags.ContainsKey("Location"))

            {

                $r.Tags["Location"] = $Location

            }

            else

            {

                $r.Tags.Add("Location", $Location)

            }



            #Setting the tags on the resource

            Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $r.Tags -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force

        }

        else

        {

            #Setting the tags on a resource which doesn't have tags

            Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ Application=$Application; subCat=$subCat; Environment=$Environment; AppOwner=$AppOwner; Location=$Location } -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force

        }

    }

    else

    {

        Write-Host "Resource Not Found with Resource Id: " + $ResourceId

    }





}
```

**Error message**

```
 Get-AzureRmResource : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

    At line:10 char:43

    +      $r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $ResourceId -ErrorAction Co ...

    +                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~

        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzureRmResource], ParameterBindingValidationException

        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet
```

Comment: Great first submission. Shared your code, stated your end goal, etc. Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first thing's first: You can't do this without the ResourceGroupName, and the best way to add it in your case is as a column in your csv.

Secondly, everybody starts somewhere so never apologize. :) I commented about most of the issues I fixed in the code below. Your biggest problems were a) you didn't actually load the data from the CSV (you only created a variable with the file path in it), and b) you were attempting to use `$ResourceID` without ever populating it.

I cleaned things up a bit and it works now, and will throw an error if it can't find the VM. Here are the contents of my test.csv, with one good VM and one that doesn't exist.

```
VMName,ResourceGroup,Application,SubCat,Environment,AppOwner,Location
test-rm-01,test-rg,Thing,Subs,Dev,Nick,Europe
clambake,mygroup,,,,,
```

And here's the re-worked script.

```
# Set Credentials (Fixed this up)

$context = Get-AzureRmContext
if ($context.Account -eq $null) {
    Login-AzureRmAccount
}

# Select Azure Subscription

$subscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title "Select an Azure Subscription ..." -PassThru).SubscriptionId

#Select specified subscription ID

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$InputCSVFilePath = "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\test.csv"

################
#
# Here you were missing loading the actual data. Also renamed the items in the loop, nitpicking. :)
#
################

$csvItems = Import-Csv $InputCSVFilePath

################

#Start loop

foreach ($item in $csvItems)
{
    ################
    #
    # Change here, you need ResourceGroupName
    # Also cleared r because if you don't, it will still have a value if no matching VM is found, which would re-tag the previous item from the loop, instead of throwing an error that the VM was not found
    #
    ################ 

    Clear-Variable r

    $r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $item.ResourceGroup -Name $item.VMName -ErrorAction Continue

    ################ 

    if ($r -ne $null)
    {
        if ($r.Tags)
        {
            # Tag - Application

            if ($r.Tags.ContainsKey("Application"))
            {
                $r.Tags["Application"] = $item.Application
            }
            else
            {
                $r.Tags.Add("Application", $item.Application)
            }

            # Tag - SubCat

            if ($r.Tags.ContainsKey("subCat"))
            {
                $r.Tags["subCat"] = $item.subCat
            }
            else
            {
                $r.Tags.Add("subCat", $item.subCat)
            }

            # Tag - Environment

            if ($r.Tags.ContainsKey("Environment"))
            {
                $r.Tags["Environment"] = $item.Environment
            }
            else
            {
                $r.Tags.Add("Environment", $item.Environment)
            }

            # Tag - AppOwner

            if ($r.Tags.ContainsKey("AppOwner"))
            {
                $r.Tags["AppOwner"] = $item.AppOwner
            }
            else
            {
                $r.Tags.Add("AppOwner", $item.AppOwner)
            }

            # Tag - Location

            if ($r.Tags.ContainsKey("Location"))
            {
                $r.Tags["Location"] = $item.Location
            }

            else
            {
                $r.Tags.Add("Location", $item.Location)
            }

            #Setting the tags on the resource

            Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $r.Tags -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
        }

        else
        {
            #Setting the tags on a resource which doesn't have tags

            Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ Application = $Application; subCat = $subCat; Environment = $Environment; AppOwner = $AppOwner; Location = $Location } -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "No VM found named $($item.VMName) in ResourceGroup $($item.ResourceGroup)!"
    }
}
```